# Which side is Yamato on?

Tags: naruto

In Naruto Chapter 677, Yamato reappears again after posing as fighting against the Great Shinobi Alliance and the Kages.

Which side is he on now currently? If he is on Madara's side, why? Was he brainwashed?

Comment: My guess is Genjutsu'd, but we'll have to wait to find out more :)

Comment: Unless Yamato has become vastly more powerful it hardly even matters, Naruto, Sasuke, Madara and the Hokages eclipse everyone else in power by such a huge margin now that it makes no real difference which side they're on.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Yamato was unconscious thus his body was being used as a tool by Zetsu like how Obito corpse is being used by black Zetsu.

So Yamato is on the side of the shinobi alliance.

Answer (score 0):

Yamato is part of the shinobi alliance but currently being controlled by madara using genjutsu or probably something related to Hashirama's cells.

Remember that madara greatly desired to use Hashirama's cells in battle he definitely came up with a working idea to use Yamato who is compatible with Hashirama's chakra as a tool.