# Since which chapter has Yamato changed sides?

Tags: naruto

First I have been surprised to see another Tobi (Obito with a mask) fighting with Kages then after he revealed himself we just discover that it was

> Yamato

So my question is: in which chapter was he captured (or used) for Madara's purpose? I am a bit lost.

Comment: This entire question is a big spoiler. Be mindful of your title and please use the spoiler markdown for spoilers..

Comment: @Krazer: I am not sure to understand you. I just want to know when Yamato changed the side?

Comment: @Inanikian: I edited the question body; since I don't follow Naruto I couldn't really do anything about the title. I believe Krazer was referring to the fact that the question is pretty much a spoiler for other people who haven't seen the appropriate part of Naruto yet?

Comment: Either way it's very closely related to this question: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/9839/which-side-is-yamato-on

Comment: I have read this question but I didn't have the answer of my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure of the exact chapter, but Yamato was captured when Yamato, Aoba, and Motoi go outside to investigate during Naruto's training. They come across Kabuto as he is captured by Kurotsuchi. Yamato creates a wooden beam that Aoba can walk on to approach Kabuto and read his mind like he did with Kisame, but Kabuto sheds his body to free himself. He goes after Yamato and, before being captured, Yamato pushes Motoi out of the way.

Kabuto escapes to the Mountains' Graveyard where he and Tobi gather information from Yamato about the Allied Shinobi Forces. Kabuto also studies Hashirama's DNA within Yamato to strengthen the White Zetsu Army. Rather than kill Yamato when he has fulfiled his usefulness, they suspend him opposite Hashirama's clone for future use.

There are no given details of when Yamato changed his side, so I would assume he was forced to serve Kabuto/Madara/Obito/Zetsu while he was captured.

Comment: I accepted as answer because you helped to remember instead of searching in which chapter.

Answer (score 1):

Yamato may be under the influence of a strong genjutsu and is being controlled by Madara/Obito.